# Can not login in magento while working it on localhost

Tags: localhost, magento-1.8

I'm new to magento,working it in local while I'm working on it last night it works fine, but while opening now both the admin and  home page not getting opened its showing that `"there has been error processing your request"` this is the second time , so help me what iam doing wrong ,its so frustrating

Comment: Please post the content of the proper `var/report/<error-number>` file.

Answer (score 0):

With most things in magento, clearing the cache files and session files manually usually sorts all types of issues like this.

Go to

Magento_Root/var/cache
Magento_Root/var/session

Clear both directories, refresh your browser and try again.

Like anything with magento, before making any changes, always make a complete back up.

If that doesn't solve it, than as requested above, post the contents of the error log :)

Comment: I see the above didn't work for you, then as Jurgen mentioned, please post the content of the proper var/report/<error-number> file and we will then have an idea exactly what the issue is.  If you are unsure what me mean by this, then when your site throws the error, it lists an error number.  If you navigate to you magento installation folder, select 'var/report', open the error file with the same number illustrated when the error was displayed and paste the contents of that file on here for us.  It's the only true way for us to see what's happening and hopefully offer a solution :)